# access to C structs from Python using SWIG

Tags: python, c, struct, swig

So, i'm trying make the simplest struct access… and i can't.

yoba.h:

```
typedef struct{
    int bar;
} foo;
```

yoba.i:

```
%module yoba

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "yoba.h"
%}

%include "yoba.h"
```

setup.py:

```
import distutils
from distutils.core import setup, Extension


setup(
    name = "yoba",
    version = "0.00",
    ext_modules = [Extension(
        "_yoba",
        ["yoba.i"],
        swig_opts=['-py3', '-c++', '-module','yoba'],
    )]
)
```

run.bat:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace -ccygwin
pause
```

So, i got such output:

```
D:\pro\py\mod-test>python setup.py build_ext --inplace -ccygwin 
running build_ext
building '_yoba' extension
swigging yoba.i to yoba_wrap.cpp
D:\tools\cygwin\bin\swig.exe -python -py3 -c++ -module yoba -o yoba_wrap.cpp yoba.i
D:\tools\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe -mcygwin -mdll -O -Wall -ID:\tools\python3.2\include -ID:\tools\python3.2\PC -c yoba_wrap.cpp -o build\temp.win32-3.2\Release\yoba_wrap.o
writing build\temp.win32-3.2\Release\_yoba.def
D:\tools\cygwin\bin\g++.exe -mcygwin -shared -s build\temp.win32-3.2\Release\yoba_wrap.o build\temp.win32-3.2\Release\_yoba.def -LD:\tools\python3.2\libs -LD:\tools\python3.2\PCbuild -lpython32 -lmsvcr90 -o D:\pro\py\mod-test\_yoba.pyd
```

Everything looking fine with it, but when i'm trying to execute such code:

```
import yoba


f = yoba.foo()
```

Nothing happens, and i got 100% cpu load with "working" Python. Any ideas are welcome.

**ADDED**:

So, i'm trying to determine the "broken" code. And i'm confused… it's in **_wrap_new_foo**, generated by swig.

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_new_foo(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  foo *result = 0 ;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,(char *)":new_foo")) SWIG_fail;
  result = (foo *)new foo();
  resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(result), SWIGTYPE_p_foo, SWIG_POINTER_NEW |  0 );
  return resultobj;
fail:
  return NULL;
}
```

On the line:

```
result = (foo *)new foo();
```

What a hell?

**SOLVED:**

Use -cmingw32 instead of -ccygwin. Don't get it, but it works.

Comment: Please don't change the title of your post to solved, etc. instead, you may answer your own answer, and later accept it.